# " Using short-code widget ", Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, wordpress

I got the notice on this line : $team_options[$category->name] = $category->slug;

```
$team_categories = get_terms('team_types');
$team_options = array("All" => "");
foreach ($team_categories as $category) {
    $team_options[$category->name] = $category->slug;
}
```

Comment: So obviously `$category` is not an object. Either because it never was supposed to be, or when you instantiated it, there was an error and it failed to instantiate

Comment: @RiggsFolly how can I do to remove this notice ?

Comment: Work out what `$team_categories` actually IS. Does it contain an array of OBJECTS or an array of ARRAYS. Is it properly instantiated in the first place, etc etc etc You could start by doing a `print_r($team_categories);` just before that `foreach` loop

Comment: @RiggsFolly it works now thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that there are terms for "team_type" taxonomies.

Here is the code with few type checks:

```
$team_categories = get_terms('team_type');
if (!is_wp_error($team_categories)) {
    $team_options = array("All" => "");
    foreach ($team_categories as $category) {
        if (is_object($category) && isset($category->name) && isset($category->slug)) {
            $team_options[$category->name] = $category->slug;
        }
    }    
}
```

First "if" (`is_wp_error()`) checks if get_terms function returned an error (when there are no terms for "team_types" taxonomy).

Second "if" (`is_object()`) checks whether $category is an object and if it has "name" and "slug" properties. This should be enough to get rid of the notices.

Comment: it works now thank you :) there're team_type not team_types from my custom post type.